# Angular JS propValueAccessor innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this div here with propValueAccessor and its not working

```
<div contenteditable="false" class="terms-condition"propValueAccessor="innerHTML">{{i.body}}</div>
```

However it returns this:

```
This is a reply test.<div><br></div><div>Thank You!</div>
```

when it should return like so:

> This is a reply test.
>
> Thank You!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `class="terms-condition"propValueAccessor="innerHTML"` is concatenated. Could that be a matter?

Comment: Nope, I still have the same issue.